# Instantiating a Python object in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I am new to Python and wonder if someone can help me with this simple query.

In Visual Studio Code I have created a class in a .py file. I have then run the file.

My question is how do I actually instantiate an object?  I have tried unsuccessfully to do this in the Terminal window.

Thanks

Clos

Comment: just like this: `alex = Student()`. 
You should read the official python documentation. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have created a script called `test.py`. And in this script you've created a class called `Example` like so:

```
Class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Example() instance is created!!")
```

Now, you can instantiate this class using:

```
x = Example()
```

But if you want to use this class in the terminal, then you need first to import the class like so:

```
$ python #to enable python shell in terminal
>>> from test import Example
>>> x = Example()
Example() instance is created!!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My actual issue is indeed how to use the class in the Python terminal in Visual Studio Code.  Unfortunately if I follow your example I receive the message The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:1 char:30

Comment: In terminal, you need to activate `python` shell first before using my example. You can do that by running `python` in the terminal. Anyway, I've edited my answer to include this part.